# parse string into double getting error java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Tags: java, string, double

i get this error when i calculate the string value : **Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(suggestionSortScore) - 6)**

> 17:47:19,983 INFO  [STDOUT] [EDS ALL LIST] NOC BLACK LIST : Sugeng
>   Hindarjo
>
> 17:47:19,984 ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw
>   exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
>           at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:994)
>           at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.n51Alist_jsp.getTransactionsFromIpg(n51Alist_jsp.java:380)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.n51Alist_jsp._jspService(n51Alist_jsp.java:581)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:445)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:292)
>           at nsia.owasp.util.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:166)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
>           at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:437)
>           at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:366)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) 17:47:19,984 INFO  [STDOUT] Exception => org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception
>   occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/n51Alist.jsp at line 370
>
> 367:                 if(cekBlackListByNoc==true){
>
> 368:                   System.out.println("[EDS ALL LIST] NOC BLACK
>   LIST : " + nameOnCardDecrypt);
>
> 369:                   data[0]  = "yellow";
>
> 370:                   data[17] =
>   Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(suggestionSortScore) - 6);
>
> 371:                   if (Double.parseDouble(data[17]) < 3.0) {
>
> 372:                     data[17] = "3.1";
>
> 373:                   }

why the stacktrace said emptystring? the suggestionsortscore is filled with value "5.0".

Comment: pls. post code also. especially how do you initialize `suggestionSortScore`

Comment: You *say* that `suggestionSortScore` is 'filled' with "5.0" but personally I trust `Double.parseDouble` more than your assertion here...

Comment: Add a line `System.out.println("["+suggestionSortScore+"]");` right before the offending line. Does it print `[5.0]`?

Comment: Did you examine the output of `System.out.println(suggestionSortScore);` immediately prior to your attempted conversion? I'm pretty sure it's not "5.0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(suggestionSortScore) - 6)` -- will through an exception only when string `suggestionSortScore` does not contain a parsable `double`

Answer (score 0):

The exception is launched by `Double.parseDouble(suggestionSortScore)` and says that suggestionSortScore is empty, I'll check that again.

Anyway you can check the documentation on: [parseDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)